# AlarmServiceのonHandleIntentで、ListFragmentのメソッドを使用する方法を教えてください。

Tags: android, android-listfragment

AlarmServiceのonHandleIntentで、ListFragmentのメソッドを使用する方法を教えてください。

詳細：
　お世話になっております。
　現在、ListFragmentの内容を「一日の指定時間に追加する」という動きをつくろうとしております。
　http://android.keicode.com/basics/services-schedule-with-alarmmanager.php
のサイトを参考にAlarmServiceを利用しようと考えております。
　自作のListFragmentにメソッド（alarmAdd()）を追加し、MyService3.javaのonHandleIntent(Intent intent)で呼びだそうとしているのですが、アプリが異常終了してしまいます。
　Logも表示されずに終了するため困っております。
　アドバイスを頂けないでしょうか？

また、「一日の指定時間に追加する」という動作に、適した他の方法がありましたらご教授いだければ幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたいます。

ご質問を頂いた情報を追加させていただきます。

ListFragmentに表示するデータは、サーバー上のJSONデータを習得し、ListFragment内で解析しております。
　JSONの内容は、
　　１　画像（PNG）のアドレス
　　２　View表示のタイトル名
　　３　遷移先のHPアドレス
　の３点です。

１、２は「JSONArray array = loadData;」の形で保持。
　３のみ「openFileOutput」で内部ストレージに保存しております。

テストとしてopenFileOutputにボタンを設置し、それを押すごとにListViewに望んだ形で追加できるようになっております。

Comment: `ListFragment`に表示するデータは、どこから取得していますか？(DB/SharedPreferences/File)

Comment: お世話になっております。
　ご質問を頂いた情報を追加させていただきました。
　よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: お世話になっております。
ご質問したまま削除して良いものか迷ったので、結果だけご報告します。
上の動作を実現するため、「各表示用データ」をアプリ内で記録、また、「指定時間を経過したデータ」も同時に記録し、アプリ起動時に指定時間を経過したデータ」に呼び出し「経過した日数分の表示用データ」を呼び出すことで実現しました。安定動作させるのに時間がかかりましたが、現在、無事、動作しております。
ご迷惑をお掛けしました。